# How to exit MIT Scheme without confirmation?

Tags: mit-scheme

Suppose I have this program (`myprog.scm`):

```
(display "Hello")
(newline)
(exit)
```

I now run the program using: `mit-scheme --load 'myprog.scm'`.

But when MIT Scheme reaches the `(exit)`, it prompts for confirmation `Kill Scheme (y or n)?`. How can I exit MIT Scheme without the exit confirmation prompt?

Answer (score 0):

As I see in my mit-gnu scheme there are `%exit` function exists which don't prompts before exit:

```scheme
1 ]=> (pp exit)
(named-lambda (exit #!optional integer)
  (hook/exit (if (eq? integer #!default) #f integer)))
;Unspecified return value

1 ]=> (pp hook/exit)
(named-lambda (default/exit integer)
  (if (prompt-for-confirmation "Kill Scheme")
      (%exit integer)))
;Unspecified return value
```